# Edit 'Shopping Cart is Empty' page

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

I am trying to edit Shopping Cart is Empty page. But I am unable to . I am editing  checkout/cart/noItems.phtml in template directory. I tried to editby writing a "test" in html and also echoing via php, but nothing shows in front end

Answer (score 1):

You're editing the right file. I have a few suggestions.

1. Make sure you clear the caches every time you modify phtml files.
2. Enable `Template Path Hints` in `System > Configuration > Developer`. Change to a store view to see this field. Go back to empty cart page and you should see the right path.
3. If 2 is not an option (e.g. you're on a live site), check `System > Configuration > Design`. See `Current Package Name` and `Templates` fields. You have to edit `app/design/frontend/[Current Package Name]/[Templates]/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml`. If `Templates` field was empty replace it by `default`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes already followed step 3. and cache is disabled

Comment: Can you try enabling Template Path Hints?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the file in folder:
`app/design/frontend/[Current Package Name]/[Templates]/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml`

if you can't find the phtml file in your theme at the location `checkout/cart/noItems.phtml`, you have to include it yourself.

#### How do i include noItems.phtml?

You can find a copy of the file at:
`/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml`.

Just copy and paste it in `app/design/frontend/[Current Package Name]/[Templates]/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml` and you're good to go.

#### What to do after I changed the file?

Be sure to empty the Magento cache in `system >> Cache Management` and then the button `Flush Magento Cache`

If you use caching plugins like `Redis`, `Memcache` or `Varnish` be sure to flush those cache systems too.

Comment: If this answered your question please don't forget to accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if cache is enabled (System -> Cache Management). I so refresh it or disable.
2. Make sure that you are editing proper file (in your theme directory).

Comment: cache is already disabled and file is in the current directory i.e rwd

Comment: Are you sure that this file is used? Try to remove all content and see what happens.

Answer (score -3):

I have magento 1.9

I had a similar problem in Internet Explorer, it was not able to add products to shopping cart (error message cart is empty).

I fixed the problem by going to the control panel on my computer and go into security and set the Internet Security settings to medium - high (my computer security settings was set too high) and was not allowing the Magento shopping cart to work in Internet Explorer, also I do not think this was the problem.

But I also changed the cookie lifetime from 5400 to 86400 (cookie lifetime is change in Magento - Configuration- Web- Cookie Lifetime

It works fine now!

Comment: This is a totally different problem.